# How do i pull time duration from "hours worked" field?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Im new to SQL, so still learning the ropes, I'm hoping someone can assist me with this basic query. I cant seem to find anything online (probably not searching for the right thing).

Im trying to get the duration of time worked in a day, and i need to extract that from the below column.

```
+---------------------+
| hours               |
+---------------------+
| Monday|10:00-21:00  |
| Tuesday|10:00-21:00 |
| Friday|10:00-21:00  |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: What is the data-type of the `hours` column? I hope it's not a `text`/`varchar` column...

Comment: Are you really storing all this information as a concatenated string in a single column?

Comment: *Structured* Query Language. One column per data element type. The type of the column also needs to map to its data. That way [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) can be used to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presenting here steps without specific syntax (it is a long time since I worked with MySQL and hence my recollection is a little blur...):

1. Isolate the time window part by splitting the string using "|" as separator,
2. Split the string into two (using the "-" as separator),
3. Cast the two parts (strings) into TIME type,
4. Use a SQL function to calculate the difference (TIMEDIFF; see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp)).
5. Since the result will also be of TIME type, you may need to convert it into whatever units you need (unless a TIME type is what you are looking for).

Comment: OP states there is 1 column - with 2 different separators (| and -).

Comment: Of course! I assumed that he already isolated the part that contains the start/end type. I'll update my answer to make it clearer. Thanks for your note @P.Salmon!!

Comment: @FDavidov, thank you for the breakdown - it really did help. The logic goes a long way in helping me think around future problems.

Comment: @Limbic44, I'm pleased that my post helped you. See? The post important part is to define "WHAT", then it comes the "HOW" (which can be achieved by some GOOGLE'ing). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try This: -

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(hours,'|',1) as "Day",
TIMEDIFF(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(hours,'|',-1),'-',-1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(hours,'|',-1),'-',1)) as "Duration"
FROM example_table;
```